# ASP.NET vNext reference local project to another local project

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, asp.net-core, project.json

I am trying to reference a local project to another local project.
The structure of the project is:

Root

- src

  - ProjectA

    - project.json
  - ProjectA.B

    - project.json
- global.json

in which I am trying to reference ProjectA to ProjectA.B.

In global.json I have specified:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta8"
  }
}
```

In ProjectA.B in my dependency section I have the following:

```
"ProjectA": "1.0.0-*"
```

Nothing seems to work though. I've tried to pack ProjectA to a nuget package, but I can't seem to find information on how to reference a local nuget package.

Comment: From your solution folder run `dnu restore`.

Comment: I had for some reason put the dependency in dnxcore5 dependencies. When putting it in the project.json dependency section it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no needs to make ProjectA to a nuget package, VS do that.
From your solution folder run dnu restore.
Or delete `project.lock.json` to force tooling to restore packages